# Load content from sidebar in react

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I found [this](https://github.com/sergioadonis/react-bootstrap-simple-sidebar) template of react sidebar which I have implemented successfully. However, I am stuck on how to load the content.

```
<SubMenu
   title="Users"
   icon={faBriefcase}
   items={["Create", "List"]}
/>
```

How do I route the content I want to show when a menu item is selected? (either Create or List in the example above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As React provides with `Link` Tags to Route.

Do it like this. Your items should be wrapped in a `Link` tag to route.

```
<SubMenu
   title="Users"
   icon={faBriefcase}
   items={[
      <Link to"path">"Create"</Link>,
      <Link to"path">"List"</Link>
     ]}
/>
```

As per your comment you need something like this

```
<Layout>
<App/>
</Layout>
```

Whereas Layout is

```
const Layout = ({children}) => {

return(
  <>
   <Appbar />
   <Sidebar />
    <main>
     {children} // your whole app renders here
    </main>
  </>
)
}

export default Layout;
```

You could add a `.sidenavactive` class to main tag that becomes active when side bar is opened so you `adjust or push` page content using `.sidenavactive`.

Now when you will change route in Sidebar items. Just the main content will change.

Comment: Well Zunaib, actually I would like to load my component on the content section. Like on the space beside the open sidebar http://react-bootstrap-sidebar.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/

Comment: Well then you should make a layout Higher Order Component. Look it up and wrap your whole app with that. I've put some examples for you.